# Calculate odds that cards drawn from deck sum to at least some number ("Across the Obelisk" problem)

Tags: algorithms, computer-games

Here is a problem inspired by the game [Across the Obelisk](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1385380/Across_the_Obelisk/).

4 players have decks of cards.  Each card has an integer value between 0-9 on it. The decks can be any size, and there's no other restriction on the card values - each possible card-value can be represented any number of times, including 0.

The game chooses an integer $X$, then each player shuffles their deck and draws one card.  **What are the chances the sum of those cards is $\geq X$?**

Digging into the game's code, the developers solve this problem by generating *every possible combination of cards* and putting their sums into an array, then counting how many instances are $\geq X$. With deck size $D$, this is $O(D^4)$. This is only feasible because there's a low number of players and the deck sizes are small.  Is there a solution that scales better?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with that's $O(PD + PV\log{P})$, where

- $D$ = The size of the largest deck
- $P$ = The number of players *(4 in the original problem)*
- $V$ = The max card-value *(9 in the original problem)*

---

The main ideas of this algorithm are:

- We can treat any deck, no matter how large, as a discrete probability distribution containing only the $V+1$ values $0$ thru $V$, each with its own probability of being chosen.
- Because each deck is independent, we can treat the two cards coming from any two decks as though it were a single card coming from a single larger probability distribution, whose value lies in the range $0$ thru $2V$
- Any card-value $\geq X$ *(the integer we want our sum to beat)* can be replaced by $X$ without changing the result

Combining these ideas, we get the following algorithm:

1. For each deck, create a probability table mapping each card-value to its probability of being drawn
2. Combine two tables $A,B$ into a new table $AB$, using the rule $AB(N) = A(0)B(N) + A(1)B(N-1) + ... + A(N-1)B(1) + A(N)B(0)$

   In other words, the probability of their sum being exactly $N$ is the $Prob(Card_1 = 0, Card_2 = N) + Prob(Card_1 = 1, Card_2 = N-1) + ...$

   2a. *(Optional)*: Combine all the entries $\geq X$ into a single entry by summing their values
3. Keep combining tables like this until there is only one left, always combining the two smallest tables.  The sum of all values $\geq X$ then gives the answer.

---

Asymptotic analysis:

Step 1 takes time $PD$ to calculate, plus $PV$ to initialize the arrays, for an overall $O(PD + PV)$

Step 2 does one multiplication for each combination of cards, for a total of $|A||B|$.

Step 3 has step 2 repeating a total of P-1 times. The first P/2 times, the tables will each have size V. The next P/4 times, the tables will have size 2V. The next P/8 times, the tables will have size 4V, etc. So the total number of multiplications is $$(P/2)(V+V) + (P/4)(2V+2V) + (P/8)(4V+4V) + ...$$$$= PV + PV + PV + ...(\log_2{P}\text{ times})$$

for an overall $O(PV\log{P})$